# File Properties tab access information vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, properties-file

I was currious to how I can access the information cpntained within a files propertie tab (ussualy accessed by right clicking on a file) and display that information within my vb.net application?

Comment: The properties shown from a right click in Windows Explorer, or from a right click in Solution Explorer in your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Some of them can be found in the [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

> *CreationTime* : Gets or sets the creation time of the current file or directory. (Inherited from FileSystemInfo.)
>
> *Length* : Gets the size, in bytes, of the current file.
>
> ...